# python: option menu via TKinter not showing in my UI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So i have simple `application` with 2 `labels` and 2 `option_menu`:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    import tkinter as tk
else:
    import Tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


    def update_options(self, *args):
        countries = self.dict[self.variable_a.get()]
        self.variable_b.set(countries[0])

        menu = self.optionmenu_b['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')

        for country in countries:
            menu.add_command(label=country, command=lambda nation=country: self.variable_b.set(nation))


    def create_labels(self):
        tk.Label(root, text='').grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(root, text='Produtct:').grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        tk.Label(root, text='Application:').grid(row=2, padx=10, pady=5)

    def create_option_menu(self):
        self.dict = {
            'Mobile': ['ios', 'android'],
            'Test': ['1', '2', '3']
        }

        self.variable_a = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_b = tk.StringVar(self)

        self.variable_a.trace('w', self.update_options)

        self.optionmenu_a = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_a, *self.dict.keys()).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSWE")
        self.optionmenu_b = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_b, '').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSWE")

        self.variable_a.set('Mobile')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.create_labels()
    app.create_option_menu()
    app.mainloop()
```

And when I select some option from the first `option menu` the second `option menu` changed accordingly.

And i have problem that I cannot see my `option menu` and i cannot figure why.
This is my exception:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1705, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:/HW_Automation_Python/robot-framework/gui/**init**.py", line 19, in
> update_options
> menu = self.optionmenu_b['menu'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your respective part of code to this:

```
self.optionmenu_a = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.variable_a, *self.dict.keys())
self.optionmenu_a.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSWE")
self.optionmenu_b = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.variable_b, '')
self.optionmenu_b.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NSWE")
```

- Firstly, you are saying `grid()` on the same line as declaration which makes the variable have `None` as the value. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) for more information on this.
- Secondly, you forgot to specify a master option, like `root` for the widget.